# Reload ThemeResources when resuming the App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I've defined a simple TextBlock in my MainPage:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Example" FontSize="30" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I'm using `StaticREsource PhoneForegroundBrush`. It works quite nice:
[image]

but there is a problem when the User changes Phone Theme (Light/Dark) while the App is Suspended. Then when the User goes back to the App, Resources are not being updated so my Textblock looks like this:

[image]

When I close the app and start it again, everything is ok:

[image]

Is there a method that I can put into *Resuming* event, that would update the resources so that my UIElements are visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ThemeResource, it retrieves value depending on the currently active theme.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Example" FontSize="30" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

> ThemeResource XAML markup extension provides a value for any XAML
>   attribute by evaluating a reference to a resource, with additional
>   system logic that retrieves different resources depending on the
>   currently active theme. Similar to StaticResource, resources are
>   defined in a ResourceDictionary, and a ThemeResource usage references
>   the key of that resource in the ResourceDictionary.

[ThemeResource markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn263118.aspx)